# c++ ,Mysql API LOAD DATA LOCAL

Tags: c++, mysql

I need to use mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL") to load data to remote database. The data is in the below format:

> 460022103337063 8615210477725

But unfortunately, there is always coredump when loading from the file.
The client library is mysql-connector-c-6.0.2-linux-sles10-x86.tar.gz which is the latest version from dev.mysql.com/download. We will use libmysql.so.16.0.0.
My codes are as below:

```
m_pMySQL = mysql_init(NULL);
if(!m_pMySQL)
{
    A7C_LOG_ERROR (logCat, "Can not init mysql!");
    return STATUS_ERROR;
}
if(0 != mysql_options(m_pMySQL, MYSQL_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, 0))
{
    A7C_LOG_ERROR (logCat, "Can not set mysql to local infile !");
}

if(!mysql_real_connect(m_pMySQL,
    m_host.c_str(),
    m_username.c_str(),
    m_password.c_str(),
    m_dbname.c_str(),
    m_port,
    NULL,
    //0))
    CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS|CLIENT_LOCAL_FILES))
{
    A7C_LOG_ERROR (logCat, "Can not connect mysql server. ERROR: "<<mysql_error(m_pMySQL));
    return STATUS_ERROR;
}

string load("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/tmp/TDR_HTU1_TID01' IGNORE INTO TABLE LOOKUP");
if(mysql_query(m_pMySQL, load.c_str()))
    {
    A7C_LOG_ERROR (logCat, "Failed to load. Statement: "
        <<load<<". Error:"<<mysql_error(m_pMySQL));
    return STATUS_ERROR;
    }
```

**Core info by gdb:**

```
> Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
>  #0  0xf7b362d1 in my_read (Filedes=18,
> Buffer=0xf3645a40 "460001191124402\t8613611226646\n460027014803029\t8618701483175\n460028101539830\t8615810184408\n460020264337590\t8613426218170\n460022102200877\t8615210220922\n460023100016582\t8615010067740\n460021537608606\t8615"...,
> Count=8192, MyFlags=<value optimized out>) at
> /export/home2/tmp/cteam/bs/connector-c/src/mysql-connector-c-6.0.2/mysys/my_read.c:55
> 55     
> /export/home2/tmp/cteam/bs/connector-c/src/mysql-connector-c-6.0.2/mysys/my_read.c:
> No such file or directory.
>         in /export/home2/tmp/cteam/bs/connector-c/src/mysql-connector-c-6.0.2/mysys/my_read.c
> (gdb) where
> \#0  0xf7b362d1 in my_read (Filedes=18,
>     Buffer=0xf3645a40 "460001191124402\t8613611226646\n460027014803029\t8618701483175\n460028101539830\t8615810184408\n460020264337590\t8613426218170\n460022102200877\t8615210220922\n460023100016582\t8615010067740\n460021537608606\t8615"...,
> Count=8192, MyFlags=<value optimized out>) at
> /export/home2/tmp/cteam/bs/connector-c/src/mysql-connector-c-6.0.2/mysys/my_read.c:55
>  #1  0xf7ac513d in default_local_infile_read (ptr=0xf3d59190,
>     buf=0xf3645a40 "460001191124402\t8613611226646\n460027014803029\t8618701483175\n460028101539830\t8615810184408\n460020264337590\t8613426218170\n460022102200877\t8615210220922\n460023100016582\t8615010067740\n460021537608606\t8615"...,
> buf_len=8192) at
> /export/home2/tmp/cteam/bs/connector-c/src/mysql-connector-c-6.0.2/libmysql/libmysql.c:693
>  #2  0xf7ac5337 in handle_local_infile (mysql=0x80aa6c0, net_filename=0x80add11 "/var/tmp/TDR_HTU1_TID01") at
> /export/home2/tmp/cteam/bs/connector-c/src/mysql-connector-c-6.0.2/libmysql/libmysql.c:577
>  #3  0xf7ac0532 in cli_read_query_result (mysql=0x80aa6c0) at /export/home2/tmp/cteam/bs/connector-c/src/mysql-connector-c-6.0.2/libmysql/client.c:2867
>  #4  0xf7abcc04 in mysql_real_query (mysql=0x80aa6c0, query=0x807c2d4 "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/tmp/TDR_HTU1_TID01' IGNORE INTO TABLE
> LOOKUP", length=73)
>     at /export/home2/tmp/cteam/bs/connector-c/src/mysql-connector-c-6.0.2/libmysql/client.c:2912
>  #5  0xf7ac4f75 in mysql_query (mysql=0x80aa6c0, query=0x807c2d4 "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/tmp/TDR_HTU1_TID01' IGNORE INTO TABLE LOOKUP")
>     at /export/home2/tmp/cteam/bs/connector-c/src/mysql-connector-c-6.0.2/libmysql/libmysql.c:790
```

If I change to use command line client of mysql, it works well.
This has blocked our project. Please help!

Comment: Kindly format the question, it's pain to eyes....

Comment: And don't spam tags. C++ is not C is not C++!

Answer (score 0):

Need to Changes libmysqlclient version it will work in libmysqlclient.so.16 version. it will not work in libmysqlclient.so.18 version.